# Is Webflux switchIfEmpty supposed to work like this?

Tags: java, project-reactor, reactive-streams

I have the following code:

```
mySvc
.getItem() -> returns Mono<Optional<Item>>
.map(Optional::get)
.switchIfEmpty(...)
```

The service returns an Optional.empty if the item is not found. It DOES call switchIfEmpty() which returns an Exception, but then it still goes and calls .map() and crashes (NPE).

But if I do:

```
mySvc
.getItem() -> returns Mono<Optional<Item>>
.filter(Optional::isPresent)
.map(Optional::get)
.switchIfEmpty(...)
```

Then its working as expected and only calls the switchIfEmpty(). I could have sworn this worked withOUT the filter at some point.

Is switchedIfEmpty() supposed to let the execution keep going?

EDIT:

```
Controller:
  Mono<Item> get(id)
    return mysvc.getitem(id)
       .switchifempty(return 404 exception)

Service:
  Mono<Item> get(id)
    return asyncCache.getMap()
        .map(theMap -> theMap.getItem(id))
```

In the service layer, theMap.getItem(id) (which is a HashMap) will return null if not found.

EDIT2:

HashMap<Integer, Integer> hm = new HashMap<>();

```
    hm.put(1, 2);
    hm.put(2, 4);

    return Mono.just(hm)
            .map(hm1 -> hm1.get(3));
```

Answer (score 2):

You seem to be conflating `Mono#switchIfEmpty`, which triggers if *the Mono* is a `Mono.empty()` with Java's Optional; the two are entirely separate. Your `map` unconditionally calls `Optional#get`, which throws if empty.

Because there's semantic overlap, a convenience method is available. Try:

```
Mono.justOrEmpty(mySvc.getItem()) // If this call returns an Optional<Item>
  .switchIfEmpty(...)
```

If the service already returns a `Mono<Optional<Item>>` (why?), then you can use this, which will coalesce "either the containing Mono is empty or it contains an empty Optional":

```
mySvc.getItem()
  .flatMap(Mono::justOrEmpty)
  .switchIfEmpty()
```

Comment: No, getItem() returns Mono<Optional<Item>>. It was in the post :), but maybe a bit hard to notice lol.

Comment: So if the item was found, the Optional contains the item, otherwise, it returns a Optional.empty. The switchIfEmpty DOES get called with the Optional.empty, but it calls the map also in that case.

Comment: @SledgeHammer Provided an alternate that should cover your case.

Comment: Hmmm... I'll modify the service to return Mono.empty() instead. Then I can simplify some of my constructs a bit. Thx.

Comment: Weird that Mono<Optional<Item>> triggers the switchIfEmpty though if it isn't supposed to do that...

Comment: Wait... if I get rid of the Optional, how do I handle nulls? I.e. map(x -> x.get("key")) x.get() can return a null.

Comment: @SledgeHammer You just return `Mono.empty()`.

Comment: Oh never mind. I guess you can do it within a flatmap, but not a regular map.

Comment: you can use mapNotNull in latest version